# uiLocal notification not working

Tags: ios, swift2, uilocalnotification

I set the local notification to start in 1 second from the time the app launches and then every day on that time, for some reason it's working, I'm not even getting an initial notification, can someone please help me?
[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOr0y.png)

Comment: it's working or it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add this code

```
let userNotificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)

application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

into your `AppDelegate`s didFinishLaunching function ?

And this code in your `AppDelegate` to handle it:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    print("local notification received!")
}
```

Comment: it prints out "local notification received" but no notification pop up, please help

Comment: Glad it helped. You can tick the answer if you feel like it was helpful and let other users know that this in fact helped. Good luck with your project!